# How do I make my Main Thread wait for my EDT to finish?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

So I'm making a battleship game and I made a PlayingField class where a JFrame will open and prompt the user to place ships by using JButtons. This happens in the constructor and I naively used a while loop to make the main thread wait for EDT to tell it is finished. Is there a better "thread way" to do it?

```
class PlayingField extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
//fields
boolean isRunning = true;
    public PlayingField(){
        //Sets up buttons
        setVisible(true);
        while (isRunning){}
        setVisible(false);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //Does logic for placing ships
        //when it is done it'll execute...
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

The hope is that after all ships have been placed the while loop terminates the window is hidden, and the constructor ends. The way I'm currently doing works only the first time I play the game. Once I try replaying the game constructing PlayingField messes up because even though EDT will make isRunning equal to false the while loop fails to terminate. I feel like there are better ways to do it using thread methods, but I am unfamiliar with them.

Comment: This is not the correct way of doing. The program will exit when you call System.exit(). The main thread can safely die as soon as the frame is made visible, since the EDT is then running and prevents the program to stop. You shouldn't create the frame more than once. Once the first game is done, you should just allow the user to restart one by removing all the ships.

Comment: @JBNizet  
This frame only sets up the board. The game is run in a BattleShipGame class where the PlayingFields of p1 and p2 are created. Does that information change anything or is it still the wrong way of doing it?

Comment: It's still the wrong way of doing. Swing is event based. Things happen when an event is fired. You don't loop to wait for something to happen.

Comment: @JBNizet I know my while loop is wrong, but I'm using Swing to fire the events to place ship. I need my main thread to continue so I can play the game since the game runs on the main thread.

Comment: Why would the game run on the main thread? What does this game do, other than displaying stuff in a frame, and react to events in that frame?

Comment: @JBNizet  
Well the game doesn't really run on the main thread but I wanted the whole game to run in the constructor so if I wanted the main method to count the wins of each player it would construct a BattleShipGame object that would run the entire game then run a whoWon() method that returns a winner on that object. I realize this might be a terrible way to do it so I'm open to suggestions on how to redo that system.

Comment: Again, you need to think in terms of events. Each time a player adds a ship (using a click), check if the game is finished, and who wins, and display the winner, for example in a dialog box. When the user closes the dialog box, reset the game to its initial state.

Comment: You could use an "observer" pattern or object lock

Comment: @MadProgrammer im sorry but whats that?